# Gnuplot multiplot: Convenient method for creating more complex layouts

Tags: gnuplot

I want to place several plots with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info) in following way:

```
 +------------------------+
 |plot1                   |
 |                        |
 +------------------------+
 +----------++------------+
 |plot2     ||plot3       |
 |          ||            |
 +----------++------------+
 +----------++------------+
 |plot4     ||plot5       |
 |          ||            |
 +----------++------------+
```

Simple nxm layouts can be achieved via `set multiplot layout n,m` (see these [demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/layout.html)  for illustration on the official website).

[`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org) offers much more advanced possibilites as you can see in the documentation: [Customizing Location of Subplot Using GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Within gnuplot I have used `set origin` and `set size` to achieve this.  However, it is rather cumbersome and requires recalculation of sizes and positions when you notice you want to change the layout afterwards.

**Remark 1:**
Often it is also useful to set the margins to fixed sizes to achieve the correct plot sizes. The auto-calculation by varying xlabels and so on would make it otherwise even more difficult to achieve the correct layout.

**Remark 2:** Instead of `origin/size` gnuplot offers another possibility using `set [lrbt]margin <> at screen` which sets plot borders. The user has to make sure that there is enough space for titles and labels (see [demo](http://gnuplot.info/demo/margins.html)). Still not a perfect solution but sometimes more convenient.

Is there a possibility that I am not aware of or does possibly a tool exist to create layouts?

Comment: I'd plot the plots separately to different files and then use a different tool (e.g. imagemagick) to create the layout.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is really a signficant improvement since I have to adjust at least all sizes of output files for my desired layout via `set term ... size x,y`. Changing the layout would also mean re-adjusting gnuplot files and running again imagemagick, tex-file, ....

Comment: Yeah, create a Makefile for the repeated part :-)

Comment: for completeness a compact solution for the given layout is using `set multiplot layout 3,2 upwards` and setting only for the last plot command (plot1) `set size 1,1./3.` But my question was of course targeted to arbitrary layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get geometry from matplotlib. Create two file **subplot2grid2gnuplot.py** and **subplot2grid.gp**. **test.gp** is an example of usage.

**subplot2grid2gnuplot.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

if len(sys.argv)<6:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: subplot2grid2gnuplot.py needs 6 arguments\n")
    sys.exit(1)

shape = (int(float(sys.argv[1])), int(float(sys.argv[2])))
loc   = (int(float(sys.argv[3])), int(float(sys.argv[4])))
colspan = int(float(sys.argv[5]))
rowspan = int(float(sys.argv[6]))

ax = plt.subplot2grid(shape, loc, colspan, rowspan)
print "%f %f %f %f" % ax._position.bounds
```

**subplot2grid.gp**

```
# Return origin and size of the subplot
# Usage:
# call subplot2grid.gp shape1 shape1 loc1 loc2 colspan rowspan
# Sets:
# or1, or2, size1, size2

aux_fun__(shape1, shape2, loc1, loc2, colspan, rowspan) = \
   system(sprintf("python subplot2grid2gnuplot.py  %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", shape1, shape2, loc1, loc2, colspan, rowspan))

aux_string__= aux_fun__($0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
or1=word(aux_string__,1)
or2=word(aux_string__,2)
size1=word(aux_string__,3)
size2=word(aux_string__,4)
```

**test.gp**

```
unset xtics
unset ytics

set multiplot

call "subplot2grid.gp" 3 3 0 0 1 3
set size size1, size2
set origin or1, or2
plot sin(x)

call "subplot2grid.gp" 3 3 1 0 1 2
set size size1, size2
set origin or1, or2
plot sin(x)

call "subplot2grid.gp" 3 3 1 2 2 1
set size size1, size2
set origin or1, or2
plot sin(x)

call "subplot2grid.gp" 3 3 2 0 1 1
set size size1, size2
set origin or1, or2
plot sin(x)

call "subplot2grid.gp" 3 3 2 1 1 1
set size size1, size2
set origin or1, or2
plot sin(x)

unset multiplot
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you very much. I just noticed that my matplotlib version under Ubuntu 10.04 is a little bit outdated, at least version 1.0 (2011) of matplotlib is required. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Two questions: 1) can `set size size1, size2; set origin or1, or2` be moved into `subplot2grid.gp`? A quick test on my own seems to work. 2) running your scripts remotely ssh requires -X option which seems to be unnecessary: python traceback message says `Traceback (most recent call last): File "subplot2grid2gnuplot.py", line 13, in <module> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Comment: regarding question 2) setting the matplotlib backend via `matplotlib.use('Agg')` solves this problem.

Comment: @Hotschke I have matplotlib version is 1.2.0. To make it work on different versions I think one should change the line `print "%f %f %f %f" % ax._position.bounds` to something more robust.

Comment: @Hotschke you can move `set size` and `set origin` if you are sure you do not want to adjust the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

A working minimal example for the given layout as mentioned in the comment.

```
set term pngcairo size 5.0in,6.0in
set output "test_layout.png"
ROWS=3
COLS=2
set multiplot layout ROWS,COLS upwards
plot sin(4*x) # plot 4
plot sin(5*x) # plot 5
plot sin(2*x) # plot 2
plot sin(3*x) # plot 3
set size 1,(1.0/ROWS)
plot sin(1*x) # plot 1:
unset multiplot
```

This solution works as long as only the first (last) row is different, everything else follows the nxm scheme. But for example you cannot specify easily a different height for the first row.

```
$ gnuplot -d file.gp:
```

[image]

However, I am still interested in other methods tackling the problem in general.