# One big and two small plots in multiplot gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot three different plots on the same canvas using the multiplot mode of gnuplot (version 5.0.1)

I want an arrangement of these plots in a particular way: final plot should show 2 rows with plot A in the upper row while plots B and C should appear in the lower row side-by-side as if for a lower row we had something like:

```
"set multiplot layout 1,2"
```

How can this be achieved? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do the multiplot with the most "refined" grid, in this case 2x2 and then specify the size of each plot.

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
set size 1,0.5 # the first one has to be larger
plot sin(1*x)
set multiplot next # we want to skip the second (upright position)
set size 0.5,0.5 # the second and third have to be 0.5x0.5 
plot sin(2*x)
plot sin(3*5)
unset multiplot
```

or as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906085/2743307 it might be simpler to do it `upwards` (6 lines instead of 8!) but you have to specify the plots in opposite order:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2 upwards
plot sin(3*x)
plot sin(2*x)
set size 1,0.5
plot sin(1*x)
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Unfortunately set size is not helping me. If I try to make the size of the one of the plots very small, it shows that plot somewhere on the canvas which I don't want. Can you tell me how to make one of these plots completely invisible?

Comment: Worked finally ! Thanks a lot. I would love to see the explanation though.